# Installing android app on SD Card, preferExternal doesn't work

Tags: android, installation, version, android-sdcard

I'm developing an Android app and I am not able to install it in the SD Card. This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               package="com.developfrank.application"
               android:versionCode="1"
               android:versionName="1.0"
               android:installLocation="preferExternal">

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I use as minimum version required Froyo 2.2 so I don't have any errors about the option installLocation, but at the moment of installing the app, my mobile installs it in the internal memory.

I also have these two permissions, I put it just in case it can give some clues:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

I tried many things and I am a bit lost. Thank you very much for your help

Frank.

Comment: How many devices have you tried? `preferExternal` means just that - if the app *can* be installed to external storage then it *should* be installed there. If for some reason, however, it *can't* be installed to external storage then it will be installed to internal storage.

Comment: Does your external storage has enough memory?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: I tried just in one device, it is a Samsung Galaxy Mini with Android 2.3.4 Gingerbread. My SD card has 500 MB free so space is not the problem.

Comment: Make sure USB mass storage is unmounted before installing app.. Read above link for more detail

Comment: What I do is the following process: I connect the mobile to the PC with USB cable, I transfer the .apk file to the SD card. I disconnect the mobile from the computer so the USB mass storage can't be enable. It is a bit strange.

Comment: many times i have seen usb mass storage gets enable automatically once we connect usb cable.

Comment: but How is it possible that the USB Mass Storage is enable if it's not connected to the USB? and what's more, supossedly even if the first time the app is not installed in the SD card, with preferExternal o auto should be possible to change if from the internal memory to the SD card.

Comment: Did you tried with  android:installLocation="auto"?

Comment: yes I did, with the same result.

Comment: I have observed that if the installation of the .apk is carried out by Eclipse instead of the File Explorer of the Mobile device, the app is installed on the SD Card,but I'm not certain why the File Explorer of the Mobile is not able to install it on the SD Card.